# How to deploy elasticsearch on minikube

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, persistent-volume-claims

I am using the following yaml file to try and deploy elasticsearch to minikube:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"

      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true      
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    name: rest
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9200
  - port: 9300
    name: inter-node  
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: vol
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/opt/volume/elastic"
```

I always end up with the error Pod Has Unbound Immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. From what I've read here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/, I have to create a PersistentVolume that matches the claim from the stateful set (1Gi). However the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I ended up removing all the pvcs and pvs manually. I realized the syntax

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Already tells kubernetes to create both the persistent volume claims and the persistent volumes. There's no need no manually create a persistent volume.
After cleaning up and applying the following file I could see the elastic Stateful Set correctly created:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"

      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true      
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    name: rest
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9200
  - port: 9300
    name: inter-node  
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [doc](https://jhooq.com/pod-has-unbound-immediate-persistent-volume-claims/) the mentioned error that Pod has unbound immediate persistentvolumeclaim can be caused for multiple reasons such as listed below:

> 1. An error message appears when a pod is requesting storage resources
>    that are not currently available
> 2. Mismatch in the accessModes of Persistent Volume and Persistent
>    Volume Claim (or) PV(Persistent Volume) capacity is less than
>    PVC(Persistent Volume Claim)
> 3. nodeAffinity of the PV is missing

**To fix your issue**:

By following the  above doc try identify the issue that is caused in your environment and try below resolution steps:

1. Give a PersistentVolume satisfying the limitations of the case (a size >= 100Mi)
2. Eliminate the storageClass from the PersistentVolumeClaim or give it an unfilled value. Also you may be required to eliminate the StorageClass from your group.

You can also follow the [doc](https://www.datree.io/resources/kubernetes-troubleshooting-fixing-persistentvolumeclaims-error) authored by Eyar Zilberman to troubleshoot the error .